# Is there an option to disable JavaScript in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, javascript

In Firefox is there an option in the preferences page to disable JavaScript?

I've read I can set javascript.enabled to false in about:config but I'm looking for an option in the preferences field.

Ideally I would like Firefox to ask permission to run JavaScript like it does for other settings:

[image]
Moz to do: Add JavaScript to list above

Comment: more or less sounds like you want NoScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox developers decided you can't do it [without an extension](https://limi.net/checkboxes), except on a [tab-specific basis](http://flailingmonkey.com/disable-javascript-option-now-available-in-firefox-developer-tools/). So, go get [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/versions) or its equivalent.

Comment: OK. It really does seem like it should be built in especially because according to comments they've made security is a priority. Roughly quoting, "*All* plugins are security risks (despite the data)!", but apparently "*All* JavaScript is safe (despite the data)! BTW there's no option to disable it" Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: They realized there's Security, and then there's shooting yourself in the foot and losing market share.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts; Security is relative and varies by perspective. From Mozilla's perspecitve, their browser is a runtime, not unlike .Net or Java or Python, which executes web-applications. While from our perspective a script running from a doubleclick domain is a security/privacy threat, from theirs, it is simply another program. The ECMA specifications for javascript designate how a runtime is to render a given code construct, and they attempt to write their runtime to allow exactly the capabilities and limits described in the spec, those will not necessarilly match your desires.